# FullScreen drawer with material-ui@next

Tags: material-ui

How would I go about recreating a full screen drawer form the first `material-ui` version in the `@next` version?

I used to be able to do this

```
<Drawer width={'100%'} open={this.props.eventsDrawer} className="events-drawer">
...
</Drawer>
```

But now I don't see a way to do this? Would I have to use CSS to achieve this, and if so what element to I apply it to?

Answer (score 6):

The [Responsive Drawer demo](https://material-ui-next.com/demos/drawers/#responsive-drawer) shows how you can size the drawer using classes.  Here is a stripped down version of that demo:

```js
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { withStyles } from 'material-ui/styles';
import Drawer from 'material-ui/Drawer';

const styles = {
  drawerPaper: {
    width: '100%',
  },
};

const ResponsiveDrawer = ({ classes }) => (
  <div>
    <Drawer
      type="temporary"
      classes={{
        paper: classes.drawerPaper,
      }}
    >
      ...
    </Drawer>
  </div>
);

export default withStyles(styles)(ResponsiveDrawer);
```

The `Drawer` will flex to fill its container, so to change its size, you wrap the `Drawer` and apply a class to the wrapper.

In this demo, we define a class in the `styles` object using JSS and use the `withStyles` higher-order component to provide the `ResponsiveDrawer` component with a classes object.

`withStyles` will also accept a factory function, which is what you'd do if you need to reference theme variables.  This is done in the full version of this demo.

This approach is described in greater detail in [Overriding with classes](https://material-ui-next.com/customization/overrides/#overriding-with-classes).